# having issues using Geolocation and Google Map ionic native plugin in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I upgrade my ionic CLI version to 4.1.2, and now i am trying to use the Goelocation plugin, but i am getting this error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ionic-native/geolocation/index.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/projects/ionic/myApp3/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' h
as no exported member 'Observable'.
    node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
    [ng] i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I will like to know how to will fix this error.

I was thinking of downgrading my ionic CLI version and try downloading a new ionic application, but i find a way to do that.

What will be the code to downgrade my ionic CLI version back to version 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade your ionic CLI version by running below command:

```
npm install -g ionic@3.9.2
```

Please find release version list here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/releases

Or

Alernatively, you need to delete node_modules folder and modify your package.json file by adding below code:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
}
```

Then need to run below command:

```
npm install
```